# Как массово заполнить таблицу?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Есть полностью пустая таблица, как сделать массовое заполнение из текстового файла?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть база слов https://github.com/hermitdave/FrequencyWords/blob/master/content/2016/ru/ru_50k.txt
которую нужно заполнить в выше указанную таблицу цифровые значение в пол freq а слова в поле word, как это сделать?

Comment: Команда [.import](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats).

Comment: Или на любом языке программирования, который знаете, написать скрипт, читающий файл и в одной транзакции выполняющий множество insert в БД.